# Refactoring switch case to hashmaps: extra memory usage?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have 79 cases in my switch.

```
switch (field) {
    case "ALL_STATUS":
        allowedAllStatus = allowedValues.split("=");
        break;
    case "APPLICATION_TYPE":
        allowedApplicationType = allowedValues.split("=");
        break;
    case "CONTACT_LOCATION":
        allowedContactLocation = allowedValues.split("=");
        break;
...
```

When I ran my application to sonarqube, it asked me to reduce the number of cases:

```
Reduce the number of switch cases from 79 to at most 30
```

Now, at every case I need to perform the same function `allowedValues.split("=")`. Therefore, I decided to make a hashmap and put all the values from the cases right there and then call the function based upon the key field.

Now, I want to ask if it is efficient to do it the way I'm refactoring it - memory wise or time wise?

Comment: If you do the same operation in all cases, why do you even need a `switch`?

Comment: @marstran They are similar operations.. I can imagine 79 different variables :}

Comment: The first thing I would do is see how `allowedXYZ` fit in the problem. Using a HashMap will *not* make the problem simpler unless those can be usefully unified (and if they cannot be, disable the sonarqube warning for that case, document the reason, and move on). The code could split the `allowedValues` before hand, but it still doesn't answer the question of: "How do the 79 (?!) different but similar variables relate?"

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Anyway, there should be better way to do it than having 79 variables though.

Comment: @Akeshwar Jha, as dxdy pointed out in his answer, the code is not maintainable in this form. I'm interested what you're doing with all those variables? It might influence how to approach the problem (maybe even maps aren't any better).

Comment: There are 79 fields in the form and the user is allowed to select one or more fields to make his own form. Each of the XYZ in allowedXYZ is supposed to have a whole set of values - which would serve as options in the form. Just a rough overview.

Comment: Sounds like an [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. :) Could you please elaborate more on the actual use case? The object is a bean (value object, entity bean)? Does it represent the form or the data storage? When you say the user is able to select multiple fields this code fragment must be run multiple times for each input? Where do the values go?

Comment: @user2864740 Nothing, as always is suggested.

Answer (score 7):

A 79-element switch-case statement is practically always a bad sign. Not only is it duplicating a lot of similar code, it's also very hard to maintain. If you should ever need to change anything about it, I guarantee you will be mad at past you for not handling it differently.

In this instance, if you have a number of String (Array?) properties that you want to have available by name and read from a file, a Map is by far the superior solution. No 10 byte memory difference will ever hurt you in such cases.

Comment: I find it more alarming that he's using the same amount of different variables too.

Answer (score 1):

Hashmaps are in general very efficient. In most cases it will work with O(1) complexity, same as a switch statement does. Even though it should be slightly slower, I think it won't be even noticeable.

Of course it will take more memory than a switch statement, but if You make the hashmap a static final variable (what I believe You should do) it will be allocated only once, and again, the impact will be very hard to notice. Pretty sure you already have or will have bigger hashmaps in Your application. I would also recommend You to use [unmodifiableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) from java.util.Collections or [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) from guava, to make sure it won't be changed during runtime.

It's also a question of how often the method is used, but even if it's the key component of your application it shouldn't affect efficiency significantly in any way (but readability of the code a lot - in a positive way of course).

Comment: OP is using a dynamic map for form fields.

Comment: I don't see why he couldn't use a static hashmap. If I understand it right, the pool of key values is fixed and the operation to execute for each one is always the same.

Comment: I was interested in a question like this. Will hashmap really use more memory? What about the memory required to store the switch statement code? MOV machine instruction alone on intel processors requires 7 bytes. That is nearly two 32 bit integers.